# How to perform Delete operation on Salesforce in Mule?

Tags: salesforce, mule, delete-operator

I trying to perform delete operation on salesforce but getting error message "java.lang.ArrayStoreException" what does it means.

Can anybody explain how to perform delete operation ? My code is

```
<flow name="z_testFlow2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10" startDelay="5" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    </poll>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message"> 
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0 %output application/java
---
[{
 Name:"Thir9"
}]]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <sfdc:delete config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
       <logger message="hi.......... #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: You should send the Id of element to be deleted

Answer (score 2):

The delete operation expects an array of strings containing the ids (e.g. ["1","2","3","4"])

Some considerations:

1) The default input will be taken **from the payload** (#[payload]), in this case you have to set the list of ids into the payload previously

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
  <dw:set-payload>
   <![CDATA[
     %dw 1.0
     %output application/java
     ---
     ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
   ]]>
 </dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>

<sfdc:delete config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication"  doc:name="Salesforce" />
```

2) You can change the default expression, to take the ids from a different place (e.g. from a flowVar)

```
<sfdc:delete config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication"  doc:name="Salesforce" >
  <sfdc:ids ref="#[flowVars.myListOfIds]"/>
</sfdc:delete>
```

3) You can specify -manually the ids to be deleted

```
<sfdc:delete config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication"  doc:name="Salesforce" >
  <sfdc:ids>
      <sfdc:id>123</sfdc:id>
      <sfdc:id>666</sfdc:id>
  </sfdc:ids>
</sfdc:delete>
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Use `SELECT` query to find the record. Ex: `SELECT Id FROM employee`

Step 2: Set payload and place the ID like this: `#[[payload.Id]]`

Step 3: Then use the following expression in the delete operation: `#[payload]`

Answer (score 0):

select the option "operation" in sales force connector and write SQL query for the delete operation